# Dropdownlist value in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm learning Yii2 and I have a question about drop-down lists: I have a Nations table (id_nation, nation), I load it into a drop-down list, I select Spain, I press the Save button and on the summary page I see id_nation.
How can I view the country name?

Thanks

---

I use the following code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'p_nazione_nascita')->dropdownlist(
                 ArrayHelper::map(nazioni::find()->all(),'id_nazione','nazione'),
                 ['style'=>'width:500px','prompt'=>'Nazione di nascita ...']) ?>
```

Comment: Can we see your array for dropdown? probably you use the id in the value for option. Set name also for the option like this <option value="spain">Spain</option>

Comment: Post your code updating the question please

Comment: Try to use this  ArrayHelper::map(nazioni::find()->all(),'nazione','nazione')

Comment: you can use relation. For example, `$model->nationRelationName->nazione`

Comment: I can't use ArrayHelper::map(nazioni::find()->all(),'nazione', nazione') because I have to save the value of id_nazione(PK) in the People table in the p_nazione_nascita (Fk) field

Answer (score 0):

You can use nazione instead of id_nazione in ArrayHelper class. Need to change code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'p_nazione_nascita')->dropdownlist(
    ArrayHelper::map(nazioni::find()->all(),'nazione','nazione'
          ['style'=>'width:500px','prompt'=>'Nazione di nascita ...']) ?>
```